# Introduce me to Oracle PL/SQL extensions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm an accomplished user of SQL; I'm confident creating schema and optimizing queries in ANSI-SQL, for Sybase, MS SQL Server, MySQL, or postgresql. I understand joins, subqueries, indexes, etc., so I don't need to recapitulate any of that that isn't different under Oracle.

I'll be taking a job that'll require using Oracle. Point me to **online** resources designed not as an "Intro to SQL for Oracle" but ones that explain "PL/SQL for people who already understand SQL".

I'm especially interested in the following: a concise guide to PL/SQL extensions, and optimizing Oracle queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oracle® Database PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference (10g)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/toc.htm)  Really, what more could you want?

If you are new to Oracle, I'd also suggest you spend a bit of time learning its transaction model, as it is subtly different to SQL Server, which could bite you. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/05-nov/o65asktom.html) is a good article on it. The other poster who suggested reading Kyte is spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that PL/SQL is a more-or-less complete programming language. Crazy people like me create applications where most of the work is done in PL/SQL packages on the server.

Comment: good point, the question does kind of make it sound like the OP thinks PL/SQL is just some extra Oracle funkiness on top of ANSI-SQL

Answer (score 1):

[asktom.oracle.com](http://asktom.oracle.com) would be useful to browse.

I suggest you investigate the following powerful features:-

- analytic functions
- materialized views
- pipelined PL/SQL functions

Answer (score 0):

Read for the concepts: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Read articles and books by Steve Feuerstein, he is one of the main evangelists of PL/SQL.

Focus on their PL/SQL data structures like cursors, associative arrays, tables(PL/SQL not SQL), etc.

One thing to keep in mind with googling Oracle code, you will run into old code a lot more than you will new code. Try to learn new rather than old.

For example the old way of looping over a query is to create a cursor and then perform a while loop over it until it returns nothing.  Now days you can implicitly create a loop like this:

```
FOR Test IN (Select Ct from TableCT) LOOP
 Sum := Sum + Test.Ct;
END LOOP;
```

For optimizing queries, get SQL Developer and run the explain plan.  It may take a while to understand, but it's the best way that I found.  Also, if you haven't run into it yet, the WITH clause works wonders for optimizing queries.

Comment: The for test in (select ..) loop ... end loop is at least 12 years old, I did use it in 1997 (Oracle 7.3).

Comment: My mistake on the 'Newness' of the implicit cursor.  However, the point that you have to be careful with googling oracle code, I believe, is still valid.